# Make BFS function on graph to get the shortest path

Tags: c

I'm currently preparing an exam and I'm having some troubles implementing Breadth - First -Search algorithm about graphs.

Basically I found an exercise where I've been asked to find the shortest path between a start vertex v1 and an ending vertex v2 using the BFS algorithm. Now, on the web it's easy to find some BFS implementations in C but I'm not able to understand how to adapt it to find only the shortest path.

I've already made all the functions about push and pop in stack list and graph making from user input I'm just asking to one kind person if he can write here an example code in C of the BFS function to solve my problem.

Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

BFS is iterative, and each iteration sets the parent property of each node right? So if one of the vertex-labels in the current iteration matches your target (v2) then you are done. Next you just trace the parent property back to your start (v1)